# Generate different sequence Ids per child entity table - Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I have a parent class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(generator="idgen_di_at_au", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;
}
```

and two child classes of the same with other columns.

Problem here is that child classes are sharing the autoincrement ids across the tables which I want to avoid.

I cannot keep @Id on child classes as it is mandatory here. Is there any alternative where both child tables share their own set of Ids?

Thanks,

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why not just have each child class have it's own `id` declaration and `@SequenceGenerator`?

Comment: Parent class need to have @Id column if I define it in the given format and I am not sure if there is any way to define the hierarchy.